# Google Apps Script - Compare two sheets for changes by column names instead of hardcoded ranges

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two sheets, "IMPORT" and "CASES".

In the "IMPORT" sheet, I am importing data from an external source that sometimes have more columns or existing columns are arranged each time differently.
[image]

In the "CASES" sheet, this is where I store a weekly snapshot of all last week's imported data, and I add my additional columns with more pieces of information such as comments, next steps etc.
[image]

I am looking for a way to compare both sheets without hardcoding any column ranges. I thought the most efficient way to do it is by looking up column header names in both sheets and then checking for changes in reference to the "Case Number" row. Please let me know if you can think of a better way.

I have already managed to write a code to look through headers and identify the Index number for a specific column name, "Case Number".
This column will always be present in both sheets, and it could serve as a reference point to the row that should be validated, but it could be a different row for each sheet at a time.
I will need the same time loop through all the column headers from the CASES sheet and check for updates from the IMPORT sheet.

I only need to check/loop for changes for few specific columns from the CASES sheet. Columns names such: Contact Name, Title, Priority, Status.

I am aiming to achieve 3 possible outcomes:

1. **[ COMPLETED ]** "Case Number" from the CASES sheet was NOT FOUND in the IMPORT sheet - that means the case was closed since last week.
   ***Action***: Highlight an entire row in the CASES sheet as grey (this will indicate the case is no longer open and should be removed from the list after confirmation).
   [image]

---

2. "Case Number" from the IMPORT sheet was NOT FOUND in the CASES sheet - this means the case is new and needs to be added to the CASES sheet at the bottom.
   ***Action***: Copy the data from the IMPORT sheet to the CASES sheet and paste it in the correct columns at the bottom and highlight the entire row as green to indicate a new data entry.
   For all non-existing columns in the CASES sheet that are in the IMPORT sheet, those should be skipped.
   [image]

---

3. "Case Number" from the IMPORT sheet **WAS FOUND** in the CASES sheet - for the matching Case Number records, I need to validate if there were any changes in any CASES sheet columns since last week.
   ***Action***: If a change was found in any of the cells, update the cell with new data in CASES sheet and change the cell background colour to yellow to highlight the cell was updated. For cells without changes, skip.
   [image]

I apologise for the lengthy problem statement.

I am new to JS and GAS, and I wrote it hoping that some JavaScript expert will understand my idea and advise maybe the easier way to complete my project.

**Currently, I am stuck with finding a proper way to loop through Header Names then check cell value from the IMPORT sheet and comparing it with the CASES sheet based on the Case Name value/row.**

- **OUTCOME 1 - Completed**
- OUTCOME 2 - In Progress
- OUTCOME 3 - tbd...

I will continue to update this topic to show the latest progress on this project.
All the examples I found so far on the Internet were based on hardcoded ranges of cells and columns. I think my approach is interesting as it gives future-proof flexibility to the datasets.

Please let me know your thoughts or ideas for a more straightforward approach :)

**[Link to live sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1d4_gSlKVzaSTIVxyhe0v3Urmi6PMLcomA2lLol9Ig_w/edit?usp=sharing)**

***UPDATED code:***

```
// Create Top Menu
function onOpen() {
  let ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('>> REPORTS <<').
  addItem('Highlight Closed Cases', 'closedCases').
  addItem('Check for new Cases', 'addCases').addToUi();
}

// IN PROGRESS (Outcome 2) - Add and highlight new cases in CASES sheet
function addCases() {

  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // Get column index number for Case Number
  let activeImportCol = getColumnIndex("Case Number", "IMPORT");
  let activeCasesCol = getColumnIndex("Case Number", "CASES");

  let importHeaders = loadHeaderNames("IMPORT");
  let casesHeaders = loadHeaderNames("CASES");

  // Load Case Number columns values into array
  let loadImportValues = getColumnValues("Case Number", "IMPORT");
  let loadCasesValues = getColumnValues("Case Number", "CASES");
  // Convert to 1D array
  let newImportValues = loadImportValues.map(function (row) { return row[0]; });
  let newCasesValues = loadCasesValues.map(function (row) { return row[0]; });

  // Get number of columns
  var numImportCol = ss.getSheetByName("IMPORT").getLastColumn();

  // Loop through IMPORT sheet "Case Number" column to find new Case Numbers - execute OUTCOME 3 or 2
  for (var line in newImportValues) {
    var isMatched = newCasesValues.indexOf(newImportValues[line]);
    if (isMatched !== -1) {
      

      // "Case Number" from the IMPORT sheet WAS FOUND in the CASES sheet - EXECUTE OUTCOME 3
      // ****************************************************************************************
      // For the matching Case Number records, I need to validate if there were any changes in any CASES sheet columns since last week
      // Action: If a change was found in any of the cells, update the cell with new data in CASES sheet 
      // and change the cell background colour to yellow to highlight the cell was updated. For cells without changes, skip.

      
    } else {
      
      // "Case Number" from the IMPORT sheet was NOT FOUND in the CASES sheet - EXECUTE OUTCOME 2
      // ****************************************************************************************
      // Copy the new data row from the IMPORT sheet to the CASES sheet and paste it in the correct columns 
      // at the bottom and highlight the entire row as green to indicate a new data entry.
      // For all non-existing/not matching column names in the CASES sheet that are not in IMPORT sheet, those should be skipped.
      
    }
  }
}

// COMPLETED (Outcome 1) - Highlight entire row grey for missing values in CASES sheet
function closedCases() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // Load all Casen Number columns values into array
  var importValues = getColumnValues("Case Number", "IMPORT");
  var casesValues = getColumnValues("Case Number", "CASES");

  // Convert to 1D array
  var newImportValues = importValues.map(function (row) { return row[0]; });
  var newCasesValues = casesValues.map(function (row) { return row[0]; });

  // Get column index number for Case Number
  var activeCol = getColumnIndex("Case Number", "CASES");

  // Get number of columns
  var numCol = ss.getSheetByName("CASES").getLastColumn();

  // Loop though CASES "Case Number" column and highlight closed cases (not found in IMPORT tab)
  for (var line in newCasesValues) {
    var isMatched = newImportValues.indexOf(newCasesValues[line]);
    if (isMatched !== -1) {

      // If found then...
      ss.getSheetByName("CASES").getRange(+line + 2, 1, 1, numCol).setBackground(null);

    } else {
      // Higlight row with missing cases - grey
      ss.getSheetByName("CASES").getRange(+line + 2, 1, 1, numCol).setBackground("#d9d9d9");
    };
  }
}

// Load column values
function getColumnValues(label, sheetName) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);

  // Get column number for Case Number
  var colIndex = getColumnIndex(label, sheetName);

  // Get number of rows in Case Number
  var numRows = ss.getLastRow() - 1;

  // Load Case Number values into array
  var colValues = ss.getRange(2, colIndex, numRows, 1).getValues();

  return colValues;

}

// Load column header names
function loadHeaderNames(sheetName) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);

  let HeaderArray = ss.getRange(1, 1, 1, ss.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  let colidx = {};
  HeaderArray.forEach((h, i) => colidx[h] = i);

  return HeaderArray;

}

// Get column name index value
function getColumnIndex(label, sheetName) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);

  // Find last column
  var lc = ss.getLastColumn();

  // Load headers into array
  var lookupRangeValues = ss.getRange(1, 1, 1, lc).getValues()[0];

  // Search for label and return the column number
  var index = lookupRangeValues.indexOf(label) + 1;

  return index;

}
```

Comment: `let headerArray = sheet.getRange(colrow,1,1,sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];let colidx = {};headerArray.forEach((h,i) => colidx[h] = i);`

Comment: Hi there @Omen! I strongly suggest you try the fix commented by Cooper. Please answer back clarifying if it helped you or not.

Comment: It is unclear why you would need to use a script, as that sounds doable with plain vanilla spreadsheet formulas. Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data, and showing your _hand-entered_ expected results there. Also see [Compare two sheets for changes by column names instead of hardcoded ranges](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/113700259).

Comment: Hi, @Cooper thanks for your code! I was able to complete Outcome1 and I also managed to implement your code for headers. However, I can't figure out the way to go through the sheet and copy data over to another sheet in proper columns that are looked up using column name values... Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi all, please find a link to a sheet with latest code. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1d4_gSlKVzaSTIVxyhe0v3Urmi6PMLcomA2lLol9Ig_w/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

One way to make all this processing much easier is to reorder the columns so that they always fall in the same place, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  iferror( 
    vlookup( 
      hlookup("Case Number"; IMPORT!A1:G; row(IMPORT!A2:G); false); 
      { 
        hlookup("Case Number"; IMPORT!A1:G; row(IMPORT!A1:G); false) \ 
        IMPORT!A1:G 
      }; 
      match(IMPORT!A1:G1; CASES!A1:G1; 0) + 1; 
      false 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

The formula will reorder the columns in `IMPORT` so that the columns are in the same order as they are listed in `CASES!A1:G1`.

You can then use further formulas or script functions to work on the data, confident that a particular kind of data will always be in the same column. For instance, you can list closed cases with something like this:

`=filter( 'CASES normalized'!A2:G; isna(match('CASES normalized'!C2:C; 'IMPORT normalized'!C2:C; 0)) )`

...and open cases like this:

`=filter( 'CASES normalized'!A2:G; match('CASES normalized'!C2:C; 'IMPORT normalized'!C2:C; 0) )`

See your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1d4_gSlKVzaSTIVxyhe0v3Urmi6PMLcomA2lLol9Ig_w/edit#gid=66141956).